# Maximum call stack size exceeded when using turf difference between 2 simple polygons

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, polygon, difference, turfjs

I am getting following error:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
> [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzUxm.png)

When I use turf difference function between 2 polygons:

```
    const pol1 = [
        [
            [49.93317115095019, 20.170898437500004],
            [49.93927561914192, 20.16278743743897],
            [49.941126142253154, 20.165448188781742],
            [49.934096538617936, 20.174009799957275],
            [49.93317115095019, 20.170898437500004],
        ],
    ];
    const pol2 = [
        [
            [49.93317115095019, 20.170898437500004],
            [49.933680058500165, 20.170222252607346],
            [49.933758735535065, 20.170222252607346],
            [49.933803934349285, 20.170152112841606],
            [49.933803934349285, 20.170057658905122],
            [49.934306839656294, 20.169389449185992],
            [49.93434632011994, 20.16945071518421],
            [49.93434632011994, 20.16959099471569],
            [49.93448191656261, 20.16980141401291],
            [49.93457231419105, 20.16980141401291],
            [49.93466271181949, 20.16966113448143],
            [49.93484350707638, 20.16966113448143],
            [49.93520509759015, 20.169100016355515],
            [49.93529549521859, 20.169100016355515],
            [49.935928278617695, 20.168118059635166],
            [49.936018676246135, 20.168118059635166],
            [49.93660626083101, 20.167206242680553],
            [49.93660626083101, 20.167065963149074],
            [49.9367870560879, 20.166785404086117],
            [49.9367870560879, 20.166645124554638],
            [49.93714864660167, 20.166084006428722],
            [49.93714864660167, 20.165613543475054],
            [49.93742361679489, 20.16524819088677],
            [49.93755543592966, 20.165452748537067],
            [49.938504611028314, 20.16397981345654],
            [49.938504611028314, 20.163811875057462],
            [49.93927561914192, 20.16278743743897],
            [49.941126142253154, 20.165448188781742],
            [49.93988364085967, 20.16696147663808],
            [49.93981537664073, 20.166855543851856],
            [49.93958938256963, 20.167206242680553],
            [49.93958938256963, 20.167319864563666],
            [49.934096538617936, 20.174009799957275],
            [49.93317115095019, 20.170898437500004],
        ],
    ];
    let polygon1 = turf.multiPolygon(pol1);
    let polygon2 = turf.multiPolygon(pol2);
    polygon1 = turf.difference(polygon1, polygon2);
```

Here is visualization of these two polygons on map:
[polygon 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMQtk.jpg)
[polygon 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT8rd.jpg)

Is there some way to fix it? If not how can I get difference of these polygons?